# Mathematica subtracting matrices with missing value

Tags: matrix, wolfram-mathematica, missing-data

In Mathematica, I have a matrix 'a' with missing values and I have a matrix 'b' with same dimension as 'a'. I would like to calculate a-b but if the value is missing, which I denote by 'NA', I would like it to remain as 'NA'. Could you please help me with this? Please note that 'a' is of the dimension 1millionX300.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be to use a replacement rule on the result, something like this;

```
In[1]  {1, na, 3, na, 5} - {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
Out[1] {0, -2 + na, 0, -4 + na, 0}

In[2]  {1, na, 3, na, 5} - {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}/. x_ + na -> na
Out[2] {0, na, 0, na, 0}
```

Another approach would be to define an `UpValue` for `na` such that addition (and subtraction) involving it would always result in `na`; like this:

```
In[3] na /: Plus[___, na, ___] := na
```

`UpValues` would be the way to go if you are going to do the operation more than once, replacement rules for a one-off.

Comment: I am new to Mathematica... could you please help me understand your second solution? (I get the first one) what do /: and := do? Thanks!

Comment: @user1050325 look at the documentation for `TagSetDelayed`.  It allows you to make a special rule for `na` within `Plus` (only at the first level), without modifying `Plus` -- the rule is attached to the symbol `na`.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Indeterminate` for this, since it already has the behavior your looking for:

```
In[2]:= {1, na, 3, na, 5} - {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} /. na -> Indeterminate /. Indeterminate -> na

Out[2]= {0, na, 0, na, 0}
```

Personally, I'd just use `Indeterminate` to start with, instead of `NA`.